# C structure and malloc function

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, malloc

I am new to programming.The other day I was playing around with structures and pointers...I was getting errors.I tried to rectify them.It got rectified...But I cant justify why there was an error at the first place.Please help me...

```
struct node{
   int data;
   struct node*next;    
};  

int main(){
   struct node *newnode=NULL;
   struct node *start=NULL;
   newnode=start=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   newnode->data=1;

   //code snippet 
   newnode->next=NULL;
   newnode=newnode->next;
   newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   newnode->data=2;
   start=start->next;//error probably as start->next is perceived as NULL Address
   printf("%d",start->data);
   return 0;    
}
```

when replacing code snippet with this code

```
newnode->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newnode=newnode->next;
newnode->data=2;
start=start->next;
printf("%d",start->data);
```

error dissapers..How does one justify this ?

Comment: [Don't cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Note that it is unnecessary (but not harmful) to initialize your pointers to NULL when the very next thing you do is assign different values to them.

Comment: As John says, just directly initialize your pointers if that's literally the next thing you were going to do anyway. Keeps your code more minimal and looks more consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the error comes from `printf("%d",start->data);` where you are trying to dereference a pointer to `NULL`.

Let me explain it graphically:
with the firs 4 lines you get this:

```
             _____________
newnode ->  | data = 1    |
start   ->  | next = null |
            |_____________|
```

This line `newnode->next=NULL;` does nothing.
Then, `newnode=newnode->next;` does this:

```
             _____________
            | data = 1    |
start   ->  | next = null |      newnode -> NULL
            |_____________|
```

Then,

```
 newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 newnode->data=2;`
```

does this:

```
             _____________                    _____________
            | data = 1    |                  | data = 2    |
start   ->  | next = null |      newnode ->  | next = null | 
            |_____________|                  |_____________|
```

Finally, `start=start->next;` sets the state like this, and clearly you try to access a field of a pointer to `NULL` as a result.

```
                                              _____________
                                             | data = 2    |
start   ->  null                 newnode ->  | next = null | 
                                             |_____________|
```

Comment: Ok i kind of get in now..Thank you for the answer..Was quite Helpful!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are overwritting the address of `newnode` here

```
newnode = newnode->next;
```

You probably want:

```
start = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
start->data = 1;

newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newnode->data = 2;
newnode->next = NULL;

start->next = newnode;

printf("%d", start->data);
```

Comment: He knows how to fix it, his second version did that. He wanted to know why the first version was wrong.

Comment: @Barmar, well, in the second version OP is doing the same error: `start=start->next;` (overwrites the value)

Comment: But it doesn't cause a problem because `start->next` points to a valid node. In the first version `start->next` was a null pointer.

Comment: @Barmar, I don't think  so: `newnode=start=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` , the result of `malloc` is assigned to both pointers, anyway, it is not clear to me what OP is trying to do.

Comment: But then he does `newnode->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`.

Comment: That also assigns to `start->next`, so `start = start->next;` moves it to the second node.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get you: as far as I can see, in the first version: `start = start->next;` overwrites the value returned by `malloc` with `NULL` (not with a valid address)

Comment: That's correct. That's why the first version failed. The second one fixed this by assigning to `newnode->next` *before* doing `newnode = newnode->next`.

Comment: Read my answer, it goes into great detail about what was wrong in the first version and why it works in the second.

Comment: Ok, now I get you, and yes, your answer makes clear where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, `newnode` and `start` both start off pointing to the same `node` that you allocated. You then set `newnode->next = NULL;`, so that also sets `start->next` to `NULL`.

You then do:

```
newnode = newnode->next;
newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

so `newnode` now points to a different node, but `start` still points to the original node. So `start->next` is still `NULL`. Then you do:

```
start = start->next;
```

This sets `start` to `NULL`, so trying to print `start->data` is invalid because you can't dereference a null pointer.

The first assignment before `malloc()` is pointless, because you're immediately replacing the variable with something else. I'm guessing you thought that by first reassigning `newnode`, the `malloc()` call would update both `newnode` *and* `newnode->next` because you've declared them to be equivalent. But that's not how assignments work -- all it does is copy the value of `newnode->next` into `newnode`, it doesn't link those two places together.

Your second version gets this right by assigning to `newnode->next` rather to `newnode`. This also assigns to `start->next` because `newnode` and `start` initially point to the same structure. Then you assign

```
newnode = newnode->next;
```

This updates `newnode`, but `start` is still OK and points to the first node. When you then do

```
start = start->next;
```

it updates `start` to point to the second node as well. In this case, `start->data` is valid, it contains the same thing that you assigned to `newnode->data` a few lines earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In the first of your two codes, you have

> ```
> newnode=newnode->next;
> newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
> ```

.  The first of those assignments is useless: whatever value is thereby assigned to `newnode` is in the next line replaced by a different one.  Moreover, *nothing* is assigned to the `next` member of the structure to which `newnode` initially pointed.  The first assignment to `newnode` does not somehow bind it to that `next` pointer, as an alias for the pointer itself.  It just makes `newnode` point to the same thing.

In the second code, you instead have:

> ```
> newnode->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
> newnode=newnode->next;
> ```

That makes a lot more sense.  You first allocate memory and assign `newnode->next` to point to it, then you update `newnode` to point to the new memory, too.  Furthermore, up to that point you still have `start` pointing to the first dynamically-allocated block, so you can still access that, and since `newnode` and `start` initially pointed to the same structure, the same value can afterward be obtained via the expression `start->next`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Let me comment what the first version does:

```
newnode=start=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
...
// at this point, newnode and start point to the same node

newnode->next=NULL; 
// since start points to the same node as newnode, this means that also 
// start->next will be NULL 
...
start=start->next; // since start->next is null, start will be null after this statement

printf("%d",start->data);  // start is null, so start->null dereferences NULL (undefined behaviour, e.g. a crash or something dubious)
```

Your second version is different, because...

```
newnode->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
// this lets newnode->next point to a valid (new) node
// since start==newnode, also start->next will point to this valid (new) node

start=start->next;  // afterwards, start will point to the valid (new) node
printf("%d",start->data); // OK; should print 2 then.
```

I think you might confuse an assignment expression with "defining an alias":

```
newnode=newnode->next;
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

is very different from

```
newnode->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

because

```
newnode = newnode->next
```

is not defining a macro or a replacement text for newnode such that text `newnode` is replaced with text `newnode->next` henceforth. 
It's rather that the variable `newnode` will get a new value, i.e. the value that member `next` of this node points to.